# Output encoding for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, security, encoding, output

I have been working with PHP for quite a while and I have always dealt with web contents in various format. As far as I know, encoding the output of a procedure in a proper manner, according to the intended place for this output, hardens your web application against XSS attempt and, in general, injection-related vulnerabilities.

Just an example in PHP to better understand my concern: if a user provided a string which I have to display as the value of an input field, I just need to convert that string into HTML entities!

```
$output = \htmlspecialchars($input, \ENT_COMPAT | \ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8");
echo "<input name=\"output\" value=\"{$output}\" />";
```

Now, this should be enough to prevent any menace related to XSS in this specific case. Suppose that user input, when written to the database, was processed in a secure way, via prepared statements and with suitable data type binding, let's suppose using PDO. Moreover suppose that data in the `value` attribute is surrounded by single or double quotes like in the example above, otherwise properly dealing with this attribute becomes a much more non-trivial task!

In case this output needs to be sent to an Android or iOS client, is there any need to encode it so that no risk of manipulation, code execution nor anything else is triggered when it is displayed or processed by the application? I am not talking about cases in which the application actually tries to `eval` the string, I am just considering a simple output case. Is there any risk of that kind in a mobile client?

I hope my question is clear enough, if not please, feel free to ask for more details and I will either reply with a message or update the question if needed.